# Create a webhosting GIS tileserver with GeoServer (or similar) on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: geoserver, wms, web-mapping, ubuntu, tile-map-service

I am currently developing a web application with JS, HTML, CSS (you know the drill) and I am using a local GeoServer instance to display tiff files as PNG tiles in a Leaflet based mapping environment.

However, in order to deploy it non-locally, I would have to set up another instance of a geoserver (or any web GIS hosting tool) on our Ubuntu server (for which I have admin rights)

I found some tutorials online but I could not be sure if this is what I was looking for. It looked way too complicated to simply set up the geoserver the same way I did on my local machine, but in order to open a port for remote access, it seemed like one needs 100 different tools / applications / protocols etc.

What I want is simply to create a tileserver for TIFF files which can be accessed via HTTP or SSH.

Does anyone have a simple idea? It does not have to be geoserver, but can be anything what can perform this task.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: you can simply set up GeoServer in the same way as on your local machine

Comment: Ok thank you. And then what setting do I need to change to be able to remotely access the WMS tileserver from another machine?

var SSA4 = L.tileLayer.wms("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cite/wms", {
        layers: "cite:clip11_rsmpl_ele",
        format: "image/png",
        transparent: true,
        version: "1.1.0",
    });

Comment: use the name or ip address of your machine instead of localhost

Comment: Hello Ian, thank you so much. I will try that. But do I not have to enable some ports or similar? Could you help me doing that? I also see a lot of settings in geoserver which I frankly do not understand yet. Is there anything I need to enable within the geoserver itself to make sure another computer can access the files? I guess there are many restricitions for safety reasons

Comment: firewalls and such like you will need to discuss with your network team - only change you need in GeoServer is to set the Proxy URL (global settings page).

Comment: use pg_tileserv, easier to deploy and use than geoserver

Comment: @ziggy - does it support OGC standards and Styling?

Comment: @IanTurton fair enough

Comment: could use docker to spin up geoserver something like this `docker run -d -p 8000:8080 --name geoserver --link db:db -e DB_BACKEND=POSTGRES -e HOST=db -e POSTGRES_PORT=5432 -e POSTGRES_DB=thedb -e POSTGRES_USER=docker -e POSTGRES_PASS=my_password kartoza/geoserver:2.18.0`
https://github.com/kartoza/docker-geoserver

Comment: Thank you all I will try this now and will you update on how it goes